# How to create db in mongodb when it does not exist?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

**I'm working on a project in which I have store csv file data in my mongodb. If the database is not exist then I have to create it using springboot and if does exist then I have to directly store the data in db**

Previously I stored all the data in "admin" database in mongodb.

**Below is the for the same. In my properties  file I specified this.**

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to create a database just replace *admin* with the name of the  database you want to create mongoDB will create automatically

**like this :-**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/newDatabaseName
spring.data.mongodb.database=newDatabaseName
```